# PHP PostGres Inserting Two Quotes

Tags: php, postgresql, single-quotes

This one really has me baffled. The question refers to two **single quotes**, not **double quotes**. I have searched far and wide and cannot locate a similar question. Specs below, I **believe** it is something related to the PHP or Psql version but don't know, this should just work.

Consider

```
insert into table_two (character_type_field) select original_char_field from table_one where id = some_id;
```

Table one has a value with a single quote, like `O'Reiley`. Execute on the command line, it is fine, the value is inserted into `table_two` with a single quote. Execute via PhpMyAdmin, it is fine. Run it in a PHP script, it inserts two quotes like `O''Reiley`.

**How** the insert is executed - I've tried a couple ways. Our internal "coding standard" limits what I can actually try or do. First I used parameterized queries, where $params is simply [some_id],

```
$sth = pg_query_params($db, $sql, $params);
```

Then direct inline queries (nothing needs escaping, no external input,)

```
$sth = pg_query($db, $sql);
```

I have pulled the statement apart into two queries, e.g. get the records then execute an insert on the resulting data, hammering the values with all sorts of ugly escape and replace functions, it still inserts two quotes.

I have not tried PDO methods as it is not allowed in our "coding standard" but am going to give it a shot anyway. Something tells me it's going to give me the same result.

Edit: coded up PDO methods too, same result.

Relevant specs, this is being run inside a docker container (which won't make a difference.)

- PHP Version 7.0.33
- Apache 2 version 20120211 (don't hate, I have no control over these)
- PostgreSQL Version 9.6.17
- Module Version (for Psql) 7.0.33
- Docker version 19.03.12

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this issue, I have found what it was doing.

First, the above statement executes as it should. My misjudgement, looking in the wrong place, but there is still an issue. It was being immediately followed by an update statement, something like

```
'select character_type_field from table_one where id = some_id';
```

Which gives us quoted results, such as `O'Reiley`. The update statement might do something like

```
$params = [pg_escape_string($result['character_type_field'])];
$sql = 'update table_one set character_type_field = $1;';
$sth = pg_query_params($dbh, $sql, $params);
```

And there is the problem, using `pg_escape_string()` in combination with parameterized queries which already does the escaping for you. `pg_escape_string()` would set the value to `O''Reiley` then the parameterized query would do . . . exactly what I told it, escape the escaped string. :-\

Not sure how I missed the redundancy, but . . . owning up to it.